# how to compile a program in c++ using vscode?

Tags: compilation, g++, include, include-path

how to compile a program in c++ using vscode?

I just started programming since 2 months,

and I was programming on android using CXXDROIDCOMPILER,

now having a pc, I wanted to use vscode.

HTML compiles it easily.

but C++ there's no way.

I can't. pls help me.

[This is the problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztHDu.png)

`Sono stati rilevati errori #include. Aggiornare includePath. I segni di revisione sono disabilitati per questa unità di conversione (C:\Users\laaou\test\test.cpp).`

`cannot open source file error code "ncurses.h"`

Comment: cd ./folder - g++ nameprogram.cpp - ./a.exe

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak the language in which the compiler is returning your errors, however this seems to be a common C/C++ issue where the compiler is unable to locate the header files which were requested in the preprocessor directives. e.g `#include <ncurses.h>`
If this is how your pre-compiled code looks like (and this isn't production level development) then *copy and paste the ncurses.h header file into the same folder which holds your pre-compiled .c/.cpp file* and change to: `#include "ncurses.h"`

Hope this helps and buona fortuna!

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/842#issuecomment-310722840
This separate answer may also be of help to you.

Comment: yes, because ncurses is not supported officially by windows... i see it now